# Disable Android menu group

Tags: java, android, menu

I try to disable a menu group with the following code, but it doesn't work, menu items are still enabled. Can you tell me what's wrong please?

res/menu/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/a" android:title="A"></item>
  <item android:id="@+id/b" android:title="B">
    <menu>
      <item android:id="@+id/c" android:title="C" />
      <item android:id="@+id/d" android:title="D" />
      <group android:id="@+id/group_1">
        <item android:id="@+id/e" android:title="E" />
        <item android:id="@+id/f" android:title="F" />
      </group>
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

Java:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menu.setGroupEnabled (R.id.group_1, false); // does not work
    menu.setGroupVisible (R.id.group_1, false); // does not work either
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu (menu);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater ().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to user432209's info, here is the answer:

```
menu.findItem (R.id.b).getSubMenu ().setGroupVisible (R.id.group_1, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can use a group like this, but try this (its worth a shot):

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.group_1);
item.setVisible(true);
item.setEnabled(false);
```

**Edit:** Your problem is your menu structure and how you create the menu inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` due to using parent/child menus.

You create a menu for the parent menu, not the child menu, so that is why the call to `setGroupEnabled` and `setGroupVisible` fail.  You need to create an object in `onCreateOptionsMenu` that represents the child in order for that object to be passed into `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and your code to work.

Comment: I've added it (it has nothing special).

Comment: Why is this answer marked as the answer to the question when it simply doesn't work?

Comment: Why did you put up an answer that is wrong. These six upvotes should be removed

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned solution works well but it should be written within `onCreateOptionsMenu`, here is the example of it:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    // Make the menu item visible and enable it.
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.group_1);
    item.setVisible(true);
    item.setEnabled(false);
}
```